# Java Early-Access Download - What does FCS means?

Tags: java

The last Java 7 I downloaded was named

```
jdk-7-ea-bin-b145-windows-i586-07_jun_2011
```

Now it is named

```
jre-7-fcs-bin-b146-windows-i586-20_jun_2011
```

The `ea` *(Early Access)* is replaced with `fcs`, but what does `fcs` mean?

Comment: Damn, indeed. Good question. I can't find anything...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First Customer Shipment. See the [Software Release Lifecycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#General_availability).

Quote from Wikipedia:

> Some companies (such as Sun
>   Microsystems and Cisco) use FCS to
>   describe a software version that has
>   been shipped for revenue.

Comment: that sounds good, i can't believe I wasn't able to goolge it.